# Создание модели. Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model

Каким способом присвоить модели поля (`name`, `phone` etc.) или рельсы сами через БД присвоят?

Comment: Сами. `User.first.email` - первая запись из таблицы `users`, у которой взяли данные из поля `email`. Вы можете также создать кастомное "поле" (метод) для модели `User` - например: `def name; email.split('@').first; end`.

Comment: В текущем виде вопрос не имеет смысла, поскольку модель может быть не связана с БД, а присваивать атрибуты можно как угодно.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

attr_accessor

```
attr_accessor :name, :phone
```

Comment: Дайте пожалуйста более развёрнутый ответ.

Comment: `attr_accessor` не имеет никакого отношения к БД и к Rails. Он из стандартной библиотеки Ruby. Если это правда отвечает на ваш вопрос, то ваш вопрос задан ну совсем неточно.